# radio player its not working on android with html5

Tags: android, html, streaming

I developed a streaming radio app for Android and iOS with HTML5. All goes well on iOS, but the radio player is not working on android, despite it's the same code.

Comment: This question is very broad. You need to provide some code relating to the problem.